# How can I activate a guard dog on cod ghosts?

Tags: call-of-duty-ghosts

How do I activate a guard dog on cod ghosts?

Comment: What do you mean , activate, do mean Riley your sidekick?

Comment: You get a kill streak of 5 and activate it as any of the other killstreaks. The answer could have been more specific if you had only given more information. What platform are you playing on? Why can't you activate the kill streak award? What do you mean by "activate"?